# Juxtaposing (more than) two sentences that can include "and" by using "and"

Tags: grammar, commas, writing-style, lists, style-manuals

QUESTIONS:

- Is the comma used in the below sentence necessary?
- Is it okay to use different forms or parts of speech for juxtaposed elements?

  I.g. In the below sentence, a noun "development" and gerunds "reducing and lowering" are juxtaposed.

> > Engineers should contribute to increase of revenues by proactive development of good products, and reducing and lowering cost in each step of their development cycle.

Comment: The comma is fine there. In this case, taking it out is ok as well - though that would somewhat reduce clarity. *Reducing* and *lowering* function as verbs there, not nouns, so they're not gerunds. The sentence as a whole looks ok.

Comment: Using different verb forms in the two parts of the sentence certainly makes it awkward, but it's not necessarily wrong. (As it's written, you're either missing an article before *increase* or suffering from an extraneous *of* in front of *revenues*, and missing an article in front of *proactive*. Also, *cost* and *cycle* should be plural.)

Comment: I'm unclear on the difference between reducing and lowering the cost.

Comment: So am I, and I'm sorry to say I suggest the example does more to identify you as a non-native speaker than to help with anything related to engineering, costing or development.